# How can I group records and do calculations between first and last records in each group using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I have a table in Oracle 10g DB engine that contains records of service operations. The requirement is to calculate the processing time of each service request. Each service request may generate multiple records each representing a step in the process. So I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID
CREATED_ON
SERVICE_OPERATION
RESULT
FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID
```

where the last column is the identifier of service requests.

How can I calculate the difference between `CREATED_ON` of the first and last records in each group identified by `FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID`? Am I better off just do:

```
SELECT FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, CREATED_ON, SERVICE_OPERATION, RESULT FROM TABLE ORDER BY FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, ID;
```

and do some tricks in Excel? If so, how can I achieve this in Excel?

Comment: What is the field that determines the order of the records to determine the first and last records? Do we order by the Id, with the smallest number being the "first" record and the largest number being the "last" record?

Comment: Well ID should be pretty stable. I cannot think of a scenario where a later step with a later timestamp would be generated with a lower ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, 
    MIN(CREATED_ON) MIN_DT, 
    MAX(CREATED_ON) MAX_DT,
    MAX(CREATED_ON)-MIN(CREATED_ON) PROC_TIME
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY 
    FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID
ORDER BY 
    FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID;
```

Comment: That's the max and min ones, he wanted the first and last!

Comment: @sagi -  How are min and max dates different from first and last dates?

Comment: Maybe it's my bad. Max and min ones are first and last ones in terms of timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this:

```
SELECT s.FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.asc_rnk = 1 THEN CREATED_ON END) as first_crt_on,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.asc_rnk = 1 THEN SERVICE_OPERATION END) as first_srv_op,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.desc_rnk = 1 THEN CREATED_ON END) -
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.asc_rnk = 1 THEN CREATED_ON END) as diff_dates
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID BY t.CREATED_ON ) as asc_rnk,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID BY t.CREATED_ON  DESC) as desc_rnk
    FROM YourTable t) s
GROUP BY s.FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID
```

I used `CREATED_ON` as the order part, if its by any other column, change it. I also used the `FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID` column as the groups, didn't know if its that or `ID`

Answer (score 0):

Analitic function. 
last_VALUE and FIRST_VALUE have default query window  `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. In this case we want to check from first to last row in window. To achieve it i've added `RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`

```
with tabl as (
select 1 FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, sysdate -10 CREATED_ON,1  idn from dual
union 
select 1 FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, sysdate -15 CREATED_ON ,2  from dual
union 
select 1 FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, sysdate -20 CREATED_ON,3  from dual
union 
select 2 FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, sysdate -3 CREATED_ON,4  from dual
union 
select 2 FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, sysdate -5 CREATED_ON,5  from dual
union 
select 2 FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, sysdate -1 CREATED_ON,6  from dual)
select FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, min(last_d-first_d) from (
SELECT IDn,FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, CREATED_ON
  ,FIRST_VALUE(CREATED_ON) OVER (partition by FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID ORDER BY CREATED_ON ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS first_d
  ,last_VALUE(CREATED_ON) OVER (partition by FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID ORDER BY CREATED_ON ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_d
  from tabl)
  group by FK_SERVICE_REQUEST_ID;
```